# Horizontal scroll in DIV with many small DIV's inside (no text)

Tags: css, overflow, html, horizontal-scrolling

### Objective

I have a main DIV with fixed height and width, and in that I want have lots of small DIV's to float freely. I have more small DIV's than can fit in the main DIV. Then it seems that by default is disappear small DIV's **down** outside the main DIV. I want them instead to disappear to the right.

I want to trigger a horizontal scrollbar, but no vertical.

### Background

I tested this with `white-space: nowrap` as described at http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/8844.htm

And it works perfect if I have only text or images in the main DIV.

## Question

But how do I do when the main DIV contains only small DIV's?

Comment: can you also have jquery in your solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap your smaller divs in a third div that has a greater width than your main div like so.  Assuming I understood your question correctly no jquery is needed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">       
            .div_1
            {

                height: 350px;
                width: 350px;
                margin: auto;
                border: 1px black solid;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: scroll;
            }

            .div_3
            {
                float: left;
                height: 350px;
                width: 500px;
                margin: auto;
                border: 1px black solid;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: scroll;
            }

            .div_2
            {
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                border: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="div_1">
            <div class="div_3">
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
                <div class="div_2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that will work if there is a fixed width set on the containing div

Comment: YES! It was exactly what I meant. Thank you very much for your help. You are the best. :-)

Thank you also "Xavier". But I do not have to learn "jquery", so it is easier. I'm just a newbie.

Comment: Yes @Xavier is correct, a fixed width on the parent div is required for this to work

Comment: I really wish your would have used classes, you should not repeat the same id like you did.

Comment: @ JGallardo yes that is very bad practice I have correct my mistake, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 17):

I have done this using jQuery, HTML and CSS:

## HTML

```
<div id="overflow">
    <div class="container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#overflow{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#overflow .container div{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var width = 0;
    $('#overflow .container div').each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });
    $('#overflow .container').css('width', width + "px");
        alert(width);
    });
});
```

Basically the div can not use a fluid width in CSS as width is applied inherently from the parent div.

Using some jQuery code you can attach the width to the containing div easily.

[Here is the fiddle with the final code.](http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/Wq5fW/)

## OR

Use a fixed width on the container div i.e. `#overflow .container { width : 1880px }`

Comment: You have `float: left` twice.

Comment: This is a much cleaner answer and would be a better accepted answer on the question.